# Trouble with dual boot Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside already existing Windows 10 on my system. After installation, grub was only showing Ubuntu and was not listing Windows as OS on my system. I followed various instructions out there:

["GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" while using boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362689/gpt-detected-please-create-a-bios-boot-partition-while-using-boot-repair)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

but nothing works. My current state of the system can be seen from the following info file generated by boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16554206/

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into ubuntu and run

> sudo update-grub

Restart your pc. Windows should now be listed.