# Grub command line is the only thing that shows after starting my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a MSI ge60, with win8 pre installed. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a sperate partition than where win8 is. After restart grub doesn't show, the laptop goes straight to win8. I didn't know what t do so I formatted the partition with Ubuntu on it, after restarting the laptop I'm stuck at a GNU Grub version 2.00-19ubuntu2 screen
I searched how to load windows using it but it says I need to load kernel. It also says hd0,0 doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

On problems of marrying GRUB with the Win8 loader (not same thing as the Vista/7 loader) [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)

On the problem of loading Win8: burn a recovery CD on any Win8 machine, then use it to restore Win8 boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, what I do for now is typing "exit" in that grub command line, it then shows me the boot list options.

Answer (score 0):

i HOPE you did not accidentally delete any partition. To make sure everything is OK
you may run GParted preferably from a live Ubuntu USB. Then it would be only a matter of finding the boot partition, something like `sda2/BOOT/...`  Of course
you would have to mount the specific partition, first. But first things first, if 
you really want to dual boot using ubuntu I would recommend Boot-repair which 
would set things up and/or produce a detailed log of what's wrong!

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info