# Boot menu does nor show any option

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have a windows 8 sony vaio computer with UEFI bios firmware.
I installed Ubuntu onto my system into another partition.

Everything worked except when I wanted to boot wondows 8. The grub menu does not pop up on boot so I cannot select to boot windows 8.

How can I fix the grub menu to show up and show windows 8 as a bootable system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your grub menu doesn't have windows 8 in it's boot list so I doesn't show up nor does it give you the option to boot your windows 8 partition.

Try runnnig the [boot repair live disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).

```
(1) DOWNLOAD BOOT-REPAIR-DISK,
(2) Then burn it on CD or put it on USB key via Unetbootin,
(3) Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC,
(4) Choose your language,
(5) Connect internet if possible
(6) Click "Recommended repair" (write down the output help file)
(7) Reboot the pc
```

If it doesn't work you can link the output file link into your question and I'll help you to fix it.

Comment: I can boot into windows 8.
My problem is, after Iinstall Ubuntu , until and unless i boot into windows 8 , everything works fine.
But as soon as I boot into my windows 8, from next boot onwards, i do not get any option to boot into ubuntu. I and automatically taken to windows 8 login screen.

I want to get an option to select my operating system.

Comment: using this method you re-install your grub which in turn will give you your option to select the OS you want to boot

Answer (score 0):

Arno van der Weijden's recommendation may work. Another is to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can download and try the CD-R or USB flash drive version risk-free. If you can use that to boot both Windows and Linux, try installing the Debian-package version in Ubuntu.

---

***EDIT:*** If Windows is re-setting itself as the default boot loader, see this question and my answer to it: [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager).

Comment: I can boot into windows 8.
My problem is, after Iinstall Ubuntu , until and unless i boot into windows 8 , everything works fine.
But as soon as I boot into my windows 8, from next boot onwards, i do not get any option to boot into ubuntu. I and automatically taken to windows 8 login screen.

I want to get an option to select my operating system.

Comment: See my edit, above.