# Clean re-installation. Keep Windows

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows-8

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 Dual Boot with GRUB2.

How do I perform a clean re-installation of Ubuntu 14.04 without disrupting Windows 8.1.
I'd like to keep Windows 8.1 the way as it is.
And back using GRUB2.

Is there an easy proper way of doing this?

Comment: Are you still using a standard/legacy BIOS and MBR setup or does windows 8 use the new UEFI style setup to boot?

Comment: this may be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager

Comment: @mchid, UEFI. But i have both Secure Boot and FastBoot disabled. Not duplicate. It's not booting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "something else" option and simply set the "/" partition as the ubuntu partition, along with format. It will install to that partition and erase the old ubuntu partition, but also leave the windows 8 partition intact.