# Windows is protecting himself

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. It is dualbooting alongside with windows 8. The computer is a VAIO SVE151G17M and they are booting from the EFI partition.
Now the problem: When I start my computer it loads the grub asking for which SO I want to load. If I choose Ubuntu it starts normally and if I shut it down, when I turn it on again it will perfectly again. The problem is when I choose Windows! After turning the computer off when I turn it on again the grub won't show again and Windows will load again. It looks like no Ubuntu is installed.
In order to be able to use Ubuntu again I have to set my bios to load as Legacy, restart (no SO will be found), then set BIOS to load from UEFI again, restart and everything will be normal again... Until I choose Windows :(
I already tried Boot-Repair and it shows an error: http://paste2.org/kedKMUc6

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Have you turned off the Quick Boot option in Windows 8?

Comment: Yes, the quick boot option is disabled!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually it was all solved by typing this from a Windows Command Prompt with Administrator privileges: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to reinstall GRUB from that point?

In my case, when I installed Ubuntu for first time - it works, just like your end.  I then installed Windows next, and it did the job.

I then reinstall GRUB so that way GRUB will recapture both of Ubuntu and Windows and configure it to run on your master drive (GRUB only can be install on master drive, which is why you would want to reinstall in order for GRUB to detect BOTH OS).

Comment: When I run the boot-repair isn't the grub reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little bit more the solution to my problem is:

In a Windows Command Prompt window launched with Administrator privileges:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

If this is not your solution read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager).

I found this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager).