# Ubuntu 14.10 Very slow boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu 14.10 and it boots slow.

I searched the web and found some research about checking the dmesg, i did so and i found out there was some problems with my Bluetooth and i solved that.

But as you can see at the code there are many other errors that i can not solve and i need help with solving them.

The log shows ACPI ERROR

Firmware Bug

and some kind of error with nouveau.

```
[   15.927681] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[   15.936316] acpi device:4d: registered as cooling_device9
[   15.971669] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   15.971674] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD01._BQC] (Node ffff880362066d48), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   15.971681] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.104048] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[   16.119451] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119457] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119460] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=504 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119469] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=432 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119474] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=432 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119478] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=432 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119488] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=501 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119494] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=501 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.119498] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988997.424:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=501 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.235938] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.235944] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD01._BCM] (Node ffff880362066d70), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.235952] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.312047] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.312053] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BQC] (Node ffff880362066eb0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.312060] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.320074] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.320079] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCM] (Node ffff880362066ed8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.320085] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.336036] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.336041] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD03._BQC] (Node ffff88036206c050), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.336046] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.344078] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.344083] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD03._BCM] (Node ffff88036206c078), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.344088] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.360056] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.360061] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD04._BQC] (Node ffff88036206c1e0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.360066] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.368073] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.368078] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD04._BCM] (Node ffff88036206c208), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.368084] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.384045] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.384050] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD05._BQC] (Node ffff88036206c370), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.384056] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.392127] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.392132] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD05._BCM] (Node ffff88036206c398), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.392139] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.416143] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.416149] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD06._BQC] (Node ffff88036206c500), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.416154] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.424155] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.424159] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD06._BCM] (Node ffff88036206c528), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.424165] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.444158] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.444163] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD07._BQC] (Node ffff88036206c690), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.444168] ACPI Warning: Evaluating _BQC failed (20140424/video-779)
[   16.452174] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_.BLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
[   16.452179] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD07._BCM] (Node ffff88036206c6b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
[   16.452185] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20140424/video-384)
[   16.504323] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:4c/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input13
[   16.504439] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   16.504444] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   16.504448] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   16.504453] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   16.504458] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   16.514922] MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
[   16.514952] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   16.514962] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   16.514979] checking generic (a0000000 7e9000) vs hw (a0000000 10000000)
[   16.514980] fb: switching to nouveaufb from EFI VGA
[   16.515005] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   16.515217] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x0e70d0a2
[   16.515219] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Chipset: GK107 (NVE7)
[   16.515220] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Family : NVE0
[   16.515236] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image...
[   16.515241] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] ... signature not found
[   16.515242] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] checking PROM for image...
[   16.515299] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] ... signature not found
[   16.515300] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] checking ACPI for image...
[   16.769444] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.997419] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe
[   16.998725] init: failsafe main process (723) killed by TERM signal
[   17.208472] audit: type=1400 audit(1427988998.512:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=799 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.259568] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (838) terminated with status 1


[   19.038170] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   19.038353] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:07:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x0e70d0a2
[   19.038355] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:07:00.0] Chipset: GK107 (NVE7)
[   19.038356] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:07:00.0] Family : NVE0
[   19.038378] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image...
[   19.038386] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] ... signature not found
[   19.038387] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] checking PROM for image...
[   19.108025] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] ... appears to be valid
[   19.108026] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] using image from PROM
[   19.108105] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] BIT signature found
[   19.108107] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] version 80.07.a8.00.32
[   19.108428] nouveau  [ DEVINIT][0000:07:00.0] adaptor not initialised
[   19.108444] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:07:00.0] running init tables
[   19.423949] nouveau 0000:07:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[   19.423957] nouveau  [     PMC][0000:07:00.0] MSI interrupts enabled
[   19.423998] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:07:00.0] RAM type: GDDR5
[   19.423999] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:07:00.0] RAM size: 2048 MiB
[   19.424000] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:07:00.0]    ZCOMP: 0 tags
[   19.425914] nouveau  [    VOLT][0000:07:00.0] GPU voltage: 600000uv
[   19.455486] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:07:00.0] FAN control: none / external
[   19.455493] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:07:00.0] fan management: automatic
[   19.455503] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:07:00.0] internal sensor: yes
[   19.455534] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:07:00.0] 07: core 405 MHz memory 810 MHz 
[   19.455587] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:07:00.0] 0a: core 405-1097 MHz memory 1600 MHz 
[   19.455657] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:07:00.0] 0f: core 405-1097 MHz memory 5400 MHz 
[   19.455794] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:07:00.0] --: core 405 MHz memory 810 MHz 
[   19.488550] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:07:00.0] MMIO write of 0x00000002 FAULT at 0x4188ac [ IBUS ]
[   19.488641] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 2048 MiB
[   19.488642] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[   19.488644] nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
[   19.488645] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[   19.488647] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 01: 08011f82 00020010
[   19.488648] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 02: 02044f00 00000000
[   19.488649] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 01: 01000161
[   19.488650] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 04: 00000400
[   19.489720] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   19.489721] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   19.495906] nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[   19.495914] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.2 20120801 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 1
[   21.392326] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   21.396146] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   21.410315] systemd-logind[933]: Failed to start unit user@112.service: Unknown unit: user@112.service
[   21.410319] systemd-logind[933]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@112.service
[   21.412703] systemd-logind[933]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
[   21.412714] systemd-logind[933]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/112/X11-display.
[   26.586321] systemd-logind[933]: Failed to start unit user@1000.service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[   26.586326] systemd-logind[933]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service

[   16.997419] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe
```

How can i solve the Nouveau problem?

Comment: GK107 could be a GeForce 600 or 710.  Which hardware do you have?  And what's the output of `nvidia-settings --version`?

Comment: I have Nvidia GeForce GT755M.
I installed ubuntu 15.04 to see if it made any difference.
It indeed helped, with fewer errors in dmesg report and boottime improved but still there appears pruple screen for a while before bootload.
The output is Version 346.47 @Fabby

Comment: How did you install the `346.47`?  org-edgers.  if yes, try the `349.12`...

Comment: I installed it from additional drivers.
I installed the tested version.
The graphic problems seems to have been solved but the ACPI problem is still there @Fabby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the graphics drivers, install version 349.12 (the latest at the time of this writing)

For the ACPI "errors" they're just warnings that your BIOS doesn't adhere to the ACPI standard so:

1. Upgrade your BIOS to the latest version and see whether this problem goes away.
2. If the problem doesn't go away after a BIOS upgrade, contact your hardware vendor with the "errors" you get and help them getting it solved and go back to step 1...  ;-)
3. Done!  **>:)**

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I updated my BIOS version to latest version.
Grub is gone but now windows 8.1 boot time has improved a lot.
I boots in 5 seconds.
Should i boot from live USB and run Bootrepair to bring GRUB back? 
@Fabby

Comment: That would be a new question, but the answer is already handled [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) for UEFI systems.  Please accept the answer as it solves your original question.

Comment: I wish i could half accept :)
It solved the graphics error but the boot time is still slow :/

Comment: I've got a solution for that:  edit your question, remove the boot stuff, accept this answer and [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) just about the boot stuff.  It's always better to ask one question so you can receive one answer.  And a tip for slow booting: install `bootchart` and post the boot image generated in your new question!  ;-)