# Grub 2 menu isn't showing up after installing Ubuntu 15.04, Windows 8.1 is preinstalled

Tags: grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I did **boot-repair**, ordered boot order through **efibootmgr** even did grub repair from live cd. but nothing happened yet. suggest solutions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: This question is ***not*** a duplicate of the question to which Pilot6 is pointing. It *might* be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden by default. Take a look at `/etc/default/grub` and change it as necessary. [Reference.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Boot_Display_Behavior)