# Problems in dual boot with windows 10 (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, efibootmgr

Well, let me explain my situation:

I have a Lenovo G40-70 laptop, which came initially with Windows 8 as operational system, but then I upgraded to Windows 10. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04, and I did it. In the tutorial I was following, the guy told to install `efibootmgr` to change the boot order, to put Ubuntu at the first position instead of Windows Boot Manager. Curiously, Ubuntu was already at the first position, so I didn't do anything. I restarted my computer, and it was working fine. I had options to boot both to Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu. I picked Windows first just to test, and it was everything ok. But my surprise was when I restarted my computer again to try Ubuntu. It just booted automatically to Windows 10. I tried to use the test version in the flash disk again to access `efibootmgr`, but now, Ubuntu has just disappeared from the list, so i can't configure it again to change the boot order. What should I do?

PS: I'm a complete noob with Linux

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in BIOS mode, or EFI?

Comment: I used the option to install it alongside Windows 10, so I guess it was installed on UEFI mode

Comment: Can you select ubuntu in the EFI menu (some function key at power-up)?  If so, then use efibootmgr to put ubuntu first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable fast startup in Windows:

1. Go to **Control panel -> All control panel items -> Power options -> Choose what the powers button do**
2. Click on **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
3. Uncheck **Turn on fast startup**
4. Uncheck **Hibernate**
5. Restart entering Bios/UEFI
6. Move Ubuntu on top of Windows
7. Save and restart

Now everything should work!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see Ubuntu in the boot menu, try this command as an Administrator from the Windows:

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

For information regarding dual boot with windows 10 visit [this link](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/).