# Grub2 won't appear after installing Ubuntu 16.10 alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

The only way I could initially boot into Ubuntu was through the windows 10 advanced startup. The option I would choose is use a device and then an EFI Ubuntu would appear alongside EFI Network, EFI USB device and EFI DVD/CDROM. After selecting EFI Ubuntu, the system would reboot with the grub2 loader. The problem is that EFI Ubuntu is no longer listed.

I've tried turning secure boot off in bios. I've also tried changing the boot order in the "try Ubuntu" desktop terminal. I noticed that Ubuntu didn't have a star next to it in the terminal - does that have any significance? I also tried using EasyBCD and it wouldn't even initialise because it's obsolete on the windows 10 platform.

Can anyone tell me what my options are? I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Thanks

Comment: That's Microsoft for you. I'll guarantee you that a Windows update did that.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip?  Some have unique requirements. * is in UEFI menu active. Do not use EasyBCD with UEFI, and with grub best not to use even with BIOS.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager/663443

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get it working. I had to run the windows command prompt and had to set the efi boot manager path to grub. Grub2 worked perfectly fine afterwards. It was such a headache trying to find a solution to this problem but the reward was worth the effort. If you need detailed instructions, let me know and I'll post a link to where a sourced the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.) Alternatively you can find a question with the same or a very similar issue and flag your question as a duplicate of it.