# Ubuntu and Windows 10 startup

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-10

### Background Information:

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along side my windows 10. When I restart my Asus laptop, the computer does not ask me which operating system I would like to use. It automatically starts with windows 10.

### Question:

Is there a command line I can use or change something to be able to choose which operating system I want to use ?

I tried googling this issue, but it was not helpful.

Comment: My guess is that you did not install grub in the correct part of hard disk. chroot to your ubuntu, reinstall the grub.

Comment: Yes that is why, is there any way I can install grub specifically ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) question.

Comment: I took a look at the grub information you posted before, it didn't fix it. I was wondering if it matters that there are two mounts. I am not sure if I am using the right definition or not. What I mean is that there are like two disks for my ubuntu, one is 54 GB, and one is 104GB. Is this a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) for Windows 8. It is the same with Windows 10.

Go into Windows 10 and launch Command Prompt as Administrator. Then, enter this command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

If that doesn't work, then follow the steps in the original answer.

Comment: it didn't fix the problem. I followed all steps carefully.

Comment: Just wondering if having windows safe boot enabled or disabled can make a difference ?

Comment: Disable safe boot and try again. Safe boot shouldn't be enabled, or it shouldn't work with this solution.

Comment: Ok I am going to give it a try.