# Bootable usb ubuntu, unable to find in bios, change boot sequence on Dell laptop?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I installed full ubuntu on a usb-stick and it works but as soon as I've used windows 10 once I can't find the ubuntu option in my bios anymore. I wondered if it had something to do with my boot sequence so I started to look for a solution here. I have a Dell latitude laptop. The options for my boot sequence are 'legacy' of 'UEFI'. I've tried setting it on legacy and checking the 'USB Storage Device' but this didn't help. Now in the UEFI option I can 'Add Boot Option, here I can choose for 'ubuntu', looks promising, but than I have to choose between multiple options:

- fwupx64.efi
- grubx64.efi
- shimx64.efi
- MokManager.efi
- mmx64.efi
- fbx64.efi

I've no idea what I should do or what goes wrong. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Try `shimx64.efi` and if that doesn't work, `grubx64.efi`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is a duplicate, but check out [this question and its answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) If that doesn't help, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.